Why I can´t pattern match in Haskell Typeclass?
I´m trying to roll an algebraic data type Die in Haskell defined with the following definition
data Die = Die6 | Die4 | Die20 | Die100

I have defined the following typeclass
class Roll a where
  roll :: (RandomGen g) => a -> Int -> g -> ([Int], g)
  rollR :: (RandomGen g) => a -> Int -> Int -> Int -> g -> ([Int], g)

instance Roll Die where
  roll Die6 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 6 times
  rollR Die6  times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
  {--
  roll Die4 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 4 times (mkStdGen 4)
  rollR Die4 times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times (mkStdGen 4)
  --}

In case I include just rollDie6 and rollRDie6 in the instance, everything is fine, but when I try to include Die4, Iḿ getting the following error :
DieRoller.hs:16:3: error:
    Conflicting definitions for ‘roll’
    Bound at: DieRoller.hs:16:3-6
              DieRoller.hs:18:3-6
   |
16 |   roll Die6 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 6 times
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

DieRoller.hs:17:3: error:
    Conflicting definitions for ‘rollR’
    Bound at: DieRoller.hs:17:3-7
              DieRoller.hs:19:3-7
   |
17 |   rollR Die6  times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

I don´t get the point . I want to define different behaviour depending the Die has 4 or 6 sides, but looks like I'm missing something . Can you help me ? Thanks . Just to give you a little bit more of info , generateIntRandomsArray has the following definition :
generateIntRandomsArray :: (Eq a, Random a, Num a, RandomGen g) => a -> a -> a -> g -> ([a], g)
generateIntRandomsArray start end = generate
    where generate 0 generator = ([], generator)
          generate numberElements generator =
              let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (start,end) generator
                  (restOfList, finalGenerator) = generate (numberElements-1) newGenerator
              in  (value:restOfList, finalGenerator)


I'm a bit skeptical regarding the need for a typeclass here. Why don't you just define a standalone function roll :: RandomGen g => Die -> Int -> g -> ([Int], g)?

You define a function in one "block", not in multiple blocks, so:
instance Roll Die where
  roll Die4 = generateIntRandomsArray 1 4
  roll Die6 = generateIntRandomsArray 1 6
  
  rollR Die4 times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
  rollR Die6  times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
otherwise you are defining multiple functions with the same name, wich clashes of course.

In haskell, function definitions can't be interleaved. The problem is that you're partially defining roll, then defining rollR, then going back to roll again. Instead, group all definitions for roll first:
roll Die6 times = ...
roll Die4 times = ...

rollR Die6 times first last = ...  
rollR Die4 times first last = ...


Thanks a lot . It helped me to fix the problem .
